# Osgi eclipse: how to export package from a fragment bundle and make them visible to an external bundle?

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi-fragment

Starter situation (without any error):

- I have three different bundles: bunbdle A (called org.apache.xmlbeans), bundle B and bundle C
- bundle B import some packages exported from the bundle A
- bundle B export some packages (e.g. the package com.prova.xsd.config)
- bundle C import the packages exported by the bundle B (e.g. the package com.prova.xsd.config)

Now I make bundle B a fragment of the bundle A (fragment-host) adding the directive 
Fragment-Host: org.apache.xmlbeans in the MANIFEST of the bundle B

After this change there are NO errors in the MANIFEST.MF of all the bundles (A,B,C) but in the classes .java of the bundle C I have the compile error:
"The import com.prova.xsd.config cannot be resolved"
associated to the import at the head of the file .java.

*What is the problem? How can I fix it?*

Thanks a lot,

Andrea

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Answer (score 4):

You need to add "Eclipse-ExtensibleAPI: true" to the Manifest of your host plugin A.

From [Eclipse Help: OSGi Manifest Bundle](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fbundle_manifest.html) :

#### The Eclipse-ExtensibleAPI Header

The Eclipse-ExtensibleAPI is used to specify whether a host bundle allows fragment bundles 
to add additional API to the host.  This header should be used if a host bundle wants to allow 
fragments to add additional packages to the API of the host.  If this header is not 
specified then a default value of 'false' is used.  Note that this header is only used by tooling
(PDE) to construct proper class paths for building. **The runtime does not use this header 
at all.**  At runtime a fragment is always allowed to add additional packages, classes and 
resources to the API of the host.  The Eclipse-ExtensibleAPI header must use the following 
syntax:

```
Eclipse-ExtensibleAPI ::= ( 'true' | 'false' )
```

The following is an example of the Eclipse-ExtensibleAPI header:

```
Eclipse-ExtensibleAPI: true
```